# Using SignCode.exe, How to set program name in User Access Control (UAC) dialog box?

Tags: installation, sign, verisign

I am trying to figure out how to set the Program Name field in the UAC dialog box.  We have an existing Signing.proj XML file that I think needs to be modified in order to make this change.  I have searched extensively but have not found a good resource.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the situation for the exact executable name to be used in the UAC dialog when I specified a description for the file being signed, however I don't see a command line switch for specifying a description with Signcode.exe.